# What is the meaning of the colors within this string literal?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ide, string-literals, color-scheme

As far as I can tell, the following is just a simple string literal with four escapes for the double quotes:

```
string x = "{ \"Matter\": \"openDate\" }";
```

Why does Visual Studio make the curly braces and the semicolon black and `\"Matter\"` brown?  Shouldn't the whole thing be red, like `\"openDate\"`?

[image]

Comment: My copy does not do this. Perhaps it is an extension that you have installed? It seems to imply that it has found a KeyValuePair or valid json object and I would expect that to come from an extension.

Comment: Mine does this too.  And it does the same highlighting if I use a string literal (`@"{ ""Matter"": ""openDate"" }"`.  Looks like the IDE is just smart enough to detect a JSON string

Comment: If I remove a bracket or add one character to make it invalid JSON, the whole string goes back to a single color.  Pretty neat feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does appear to be intentional JSON highlighting.  If you go to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors, you can see and change the settings:

[image]

You can turn it on and off in the settings here (note I had to close the file and re-open it for the changes to take effect):

[image]